What Could Cause a Sewer Line to Crack Just Downstream of the Cleanout?
I recently repaired a leaking sewer line. I thought the joint between the pipe and wye had failed, but the joint was fine. It was the pipe that failed. It cracked on the top 160° or so.
What could cause this type of failure? Is there any way to avoid another failure like this?


was it mounted under a angle, sloped downwards

A picture of more of the pipe to the left will help.  Off hand if that pipe was not in that position before, there is a lack of support or supports broke.   There is quite a bit of weight in those pipes when full of water/stuff.

Weight above it? Shifting soil? Tree root? Careless use of tools? Where was the line?

Stress on the joint.  That, or someone took a cutting implement to it.

The pipe is improperly supported, a 12-15 ft run supported only at the ends. There was a clog in the main sewer line downstream which caused the pipe in the image to fill. Thank you for your comments.

It would appear that the pipe had considerably more weight on the left (in the picture), than the right.  This could be soil shifting, heavy machinery above it, etc.
The standard thing to do, downunder, is to embed the pipes in scoria (light fluffy metal).  This can then shift under weight, around the pipe.  I suspect sand may work as well.
Additionally, being on a lifestyle block for years, I would always put lengths of timber above a layer of scoria.  This spreads and distributes the weight on the pipe.

It looks like that pipe is in the air/above ground, maybe a basement ceiling.

it seems to have snapped, probably caused by insufficient or incorrect pipe supports. or someone putting an unexpected load on the pipe.
